# jQuery DataTables add a new row from ajax response (json)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am attempting to dynamically add a new row to my datatable. I have a successful insert, which returns me the (in this case) employee that was just created. Everything is working properly - I'm just not able to add the new row.

The error I am getting - from the documentation is this: 
DataTables warning: table id={id} - Requested unknown parameter '{parameter}' for row {row-index} [Requested Parameter Unknown](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4)

Which, makes sense, it' can't figure out which column is "name" or "status" and so on.
I'm just not sure how to tell it what is what. Trying to understand the documentation and I'm just not quite getting it (obviously). I'm so close, but need some help getting over the hump.

Here is how I am initially creating the table. "mydata" is also a json object. This is working perfectly.

**jQuery**

```
Employee.listEmployees(function (mydata) {

$('#mytable').dataTable({
'data': mydata,
'columnDefs': [{
     'targets': 0,
      'title': '',
      'sortable': false,
      'class': 'text-center',
      'data': function () {
          return '<a href="#" class="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa fa-lg"></i></a>';
      }
  },
  {
      'targets': 1,
      'title': "Name",
      'data': 'name'
  },
  {
      'targets': 2,
      'title': "Status",
      'render': function (data, type, row) {
          return '<span class="status status-' + (row.status).toLowerCase() + '">' + row.status + '</span>';
   }
   },
   {
       'targets': 3,
       'title': '',
       'sortable': false,
       'render': function (data, type, row) {
           return '<a href="#" class="remove" data-id="' + row.employee_id+ '"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a>';
         }
    }],
    'order': [[1, 'asc']],
    'drawCallback': function (settings) {
        alert('DataTables has redrawn the table');
         }
         });
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
This is what `'data': mydata` looks like:

```
0: Object
    createdon: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    employee_code: "001"
    employee_id: "1"
    name: "Joe Dirt"
    status: "Active"
    updatedon: null
```

When I add a new employee - here is what the data coming back looks like:

**JSON**

```
0: Object
    createdon: "2014-12-19 14:39:37"
    employee_code: "002"
    employee_id: "456"
    name: "AAAAA"
    status: "Active"
    updatedon: "2014-12-19 08:39:37"
```

Here is how I am attempting to add a new row:

**jQuery**

```
var employee= $.parseJSON(response);
var $table = $('#mytable').DataTable();

$table.row.add([{
'<a href="#" class="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa fa-lg"></i></a>',
employee.name,
'<a href="#" class="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa fa-lg"></i></a>'
'<a href="#" class="remove" data-id="' + row.employee_id+ '"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a>'
}]).draw();
```

Using `draw()` I am trying to create the new row without a page refresh.
Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

Thank you, @markpsmith. I have updated what you suggested; unfortunalty no success. No error(s), but no success.

The record is successfully getting written to the DB. When I do a full page refresh, I can see the new record (row) getting rendered in the datatable so I know everything is "working".

Going from the docs, I can do this to draw the table:

**jQuery**

```
var $table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
$table.order([[1, 'asc']]).draw(false);
```

I also added a callback in my initial datatable creating to just show an alert if/when the table was getting redarawn (updated above). I am getting the alert when I click the "Save" button - telling me that the table has been redrawn, but I'm just not visually seeing the new row until I do a full page refresh.

**EDIT**

@markpsmith - thank you so much for your help so far. I sincerely appreciate it.
Here is my updated table initialization:

**jQuery**

```
$('#mytable').dataTable({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': {
        'url': 'my-url/list',
        'type': 'get'
    },
    'columns': [
        {'data': ''},
        {'data': 'name'},
        {'data': 'status'},
        {'data': ''},
        {'data': ''},
        {'data': ''}
    ]
});
```

When I check the network - I can see the call getting made - and a successful response:

**JSON**

```
[
    {
     "employee_id":"1",
     "employee_code":"010",
     "name":"Joe Dirt",
     "createdon":"0000-00-0000:00:00",
     "updatedon":null,
     "status":"Active"
    }
]
... and so on ...
```

But now I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. That's puzzling - everything thing is coming across?

Just for kicks, here is my markup:

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
```

I have also tried with just using:

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped"></table>
```

I still get the same error.

**SOLUTION**

First, I cannot thank @markpsmith for all the help.

What I wanted to do was: list all employees using [jQuery Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin. I have a "Create Employee" button, that when pressed opens a form that the user can fill out and click "Submit". If the record was successfully created in the database, I wanted the existing list to instantly show the new record - without a full page refresh.

Here we go...

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped"></table>
```

**PHP**

```
echo json_encode(array('draw' => 1, 'recordsTotal' => count($data), 'recordsFiltered' => count($data), 'data' => $data));

// $data is the json response coming from the database.
```

**JSON**

```
{
"draw": 1,
"recordsTotal": 10,
"recordsFiltered": 10,
"data": [{
        "employee_id": "1",
        "employee_code": "010",
        "name": "Joe Dirt",
        "createdon": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "updatedon": null,
        "status": "Active"
    },{
        ...and so on...
    }]
}
```

Here is how my table is initially initialized:

**jQuery**

```
$('#mytable').dataTable({
    'processing': true, // true because I want server to handle the data
    'serverSide': false, // false because I want client to handle pagination etc.
    'ajax': {
        'url': 'path-to-my-service',
        'type': 'get'
    },
    'columnDefs': [{
        'targets': 0,
        'title': '',
        'sortable': false,
        'class': 'text-center',
        'data': function () {
            return '<a href="#" class="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa fa-lg"></i></a>';
        }
    },
    {
        'targets': 1,
        'title': "Name",
        'data': 'name'
    },
    {
        'targets': 2,
        'title': "Status",
        'render': function (data, type, row) {
            return '<span class="status status-' + (row.status).toLowerCase() + '">' + row.status + '</span>';
        }
    },
    {
        'targets': 3,
        'title': '',
        'sortable': false,
        'render': function (data, type, row) {
            return '<a href="#" class="remove" data-toggle="modal" data-id="' + row.employee_code+ '"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a>';
         }
     }],
     'order': [[1, 'asc']]
 });
```

I am using a callback when a new employee is successfully created (via ajax request).

**jQuery**

```
$('#submit').click(function (event) {
    Employee.createEmployee(function (response) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(response);
        // I don't actually do anything with the response, but wanted to see what was coming back.
        // console.log(data); 
        var $table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
        $table.ajax.reload(null, false);
        });
     });
```

Hopefully this will help someone who stumbles across this post.

Comment: If you've added the new row to the datatable's datasource (ie the database), then all you need to do is call `fnDraw()` on the table.

Comment: This line: `'data': mydata` - where is 'mydata' coming from?

Comment: via ajax, I have a php script that gets a list of all employees. 
`'data': mydata` is the json object(s) coming back from the service. I have updated the post with what that data looks like.

Comment: Is 'mydata' the actual URL, or a variable?

Comment: 'mydata' is the actual json data (object). I've updated above to show.

Comment: ok, so it's a variable you're passing as a parameter.  I think that's the problem. `draw` will only work if you populate the datatable using ajax in the initialisation code - see [here](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: I think this is because datatables is expecting the object to be called 'data'. In your original example, you have 'Object' at the root, the new version doesn't have this.

Comment: Holy. Cow. I (think) I got it. I cannot thank you enough for all of your help. I will update the original post with my code so others can find some help in the future.

Comment: Glad you got it working!